# python get cdf values from array

Tags: python, cdf

I have an array of numbers, lets say 100 members of that array.
I know how to draw the cdf function, but my problem is, that I want the cdf-value of each member of the array.
How can I iterate through an array and give me back the according cdf-value of a member of that array?

```
cumsum() and hist()
```

could solve my problem. I didn't find any library which I can use to give me back the value.

```
norm.cdf()
```

is not working for me (for any reason)

For example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# create some randomly ddistributed data:
data = np.random.randn(10000)
# sort the data:
data_sorted = np.sort(data)
# calculate the proportional values of samples
p = 1. * arange(len(data)) / (len(data) - 1)
# plot the sorted data:
fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.plot(p, data_sorted)
ax1.set_xlabel('$p$')
ax1.set_ylabel('$x$')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.plot(data_sorted, p)
ax2.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax2.set_ylabel('$p$')
```

Draws a line(or 2 lines) which represent the cdf. How can I get the values out of that? I mean there are values lying behind the graph, how can I use the corresponding values of my x?

But in my opinion, its not completly right. He just divides the range by the number of rows. And it doesnt pay attention to repeating values :/

Thanks in advance

*EDIT*
What would you say about that:

```
cur.execute("Select AGE From ****  ")
output = []
for row in cur:
  output.append(float(row[0]))
data_sorted = np.sort(output)
length=len(data_sorted)
yvals = np.arange(len(data_sorted))/float(len(data_sorted))
print yvals
plt.plot(data_sorted, yvals)
plt.show()
```

The result is, that the array is 5 members long. So that each member has a 1/5=0,2

That leads to:

```
[ 1  2  2  9 58]
[ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8]
```

But it should be 1 is 0.2; 2 is 0,6 (because 2 appears 2 times, so 3 out of 5 are 2 or less)

How do I get the 0,6???

I mean, I could write that in a view and sum it up, after group by AGE but, I dont know, would prefer to do it in python...

Comment: Did you try `scipy.stats.norm`? `norm.cdf(a)` where `a = np.random.randn(100)`

Comment: Yes, I tried: 
`a = np.random.normal(0,1,5)
print sorted(a)
print norm.cdf(a)`
Results are 
`a: [-2.4147745854992051, -0.97411404716276628, -0.11705125794971018, 0.13072180287558965, 1.9143845533142281]`
`cdf: [ 0.00787248  0.16499996  0.55200231  0.45340972  0.97221448`

What makes no sense for me. The cdf-values shoult be more like 
[0,2;0,4;06;0,8;1]

or do I get something wrong?